# dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: does not dismiss the modal view

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

After capturing the image, callback occurs but something is wrong cause it's not dismissing the Camera View. My code is pretty straight forward, my only doubt is that I am using a tab bar controller and pushing the imagePicker within one of the tabs, just a thought.

```
- (IBAction)imageButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
}



- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    self.portaitImage.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dismiss UIImagePickerController, not `self`:

```
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Yep, you are right but not logical for me hence I was thinking that current object presented the modal view so its duty should be to dismiss it not the pushed view itself. Anyways, its working now thanks.